# Can I make row cell value readOnly on XtraGrid just for one row?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I make a specific row cell readonly(not editable) on XtraGrid? For example just for row[0] but not all rows.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event:

```
//...
var repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit();
repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly.Name = "repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly";
repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly.ReadOnly = true;
//...
void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
    if(e.RowHandle == 0)
        e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, been trying to find out a good way to do this for longer than I care to admit! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ColumnView.ShownEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event:

```
void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColumnView view = (ColumnView)sender;        

    view.ActiveEditor.Properties.ReadOnly = view.FocusedRowHandle == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Source:** [How to Conditionally Prevent Editing for Individual Grid Cells](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A249)

> When you need to make a grid cell read-only based on a condition, the
>   best approach is to use the **ShowingEditor** event of the
>   **GridView** and prevent editing via the **e.Cancel** parameter passed to the event. Simply set it to True when it is necessary to prevent
>   editing.

```
// disable editing

private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {

    GridView view = sender as GridView; 
        e.Cancel = view.FocusedRowHandle == 0;
}
```

**Source -** [How to display disabled buttons for particular cells within a ButtonEdit column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2815.aspx)
Another approach is that assign a read only repository editor control as @DmitryG suggested and I have also implement that way some times when there was a column which contains a button.

> In your case you should create two TextEdit repository items. One with
>   the enabled button and another with the disabled button. Then handle
>   the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event and pass the necessary
>   repository item to the **e.RepositoryItem** parameter according to a
>   specific condition. Please see the [Assigning Editors to Individual
>   Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747) help topic for additional information.

[image]

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)  
{
    if (e.Column.Caption == "Any2")
    {
        if (e.RowHandle == 0)
            e.RepositoryItem = columnReadOnlyTextEdit;
        else
            e.RepositoryItem = columnTextEdit;    
    }
}
```

References:
[How to customize the Look-And-Feel of my grid cells](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A255.aspx)
[How to make my grid columns read-only](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A281.aspx)