# I want to make a entire row from a gridview "ReadOnly"

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using a Gridview and so far everything is working great! My question is how do I make the current row as a read only if a specific condition become false? I have tested and tried a few examples but with no luck. 
I found a way to make the column read only but im unable to make the entire row read only.
Thanks in advance,
Irfan

Comment: What UI context is this? WinForms? WPF? DevExtreme? Solutions may differ, depending on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make row cell value readOnly on XtraGrid just for one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011027/can-i-make-row-cell-value-readonly-on-xtragrid-just-for-one-row)

Answer (score 2):

Use event [`ShowingEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ShowingEditor.event).

```
private void  myGridView_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    var gv = sender as GridView; 
    if (/* your condition to determine if the row is readokly */ ) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```